# Pivot table on the results of a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet that consolidates raw inventory and sales.

Raw inventory takes the first few hundred rows.  Then I have a query statement that pulls sales data from Cust_Sales.

When I run a pivot table to query this to get Uncommitted inventory, the query portion of the data is not included.

I have edited the data range of the pivot table to just the query portion, and I get a blank pivot table.

Is the result of a query only available for further processing under special circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A pivot table can be created from cells populated by a query.

Check your selection range (etc.).

Comment: My mistake was a filter on the pivot table.  I asked it to filter negative values, thinking that this applied to the pivot table.  No.  It applies to the data underlying the pivot table, which is not apparent in any documentation I've found.  e.g. If I had 100 trees in inventory and sold 40 to one person and 60 to anohter, I have zero in inventory.  I was trying to hide the 'no inventory present' in the pivot table.  Instead it was removing the -40 and -60 trees sold in the underlying data.